# Hypernym for "approve" and "reject"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, hypernyms

User A goes to the web page and clicks a menu called 'Submit Request', where User A will fill out a form request and submit it to his/her Supervisor.

Then User A's Supervisor will go to the web page and click a menu called 'Approve/Reject Request', where User A's Supervisor will either approve or reject User A's request form.

Now, I was wondering if there is a term or word to describe 'Approve/Reject' collectively.

I had a term in mind, which is 'Inspect Request' but I don't think it's perfect in our case and so would like to hear more suggestion from the ground.

Comment: It's not common to have hypernyms of two antonyms. Or rather what is common about antonyms is not generally called a hypernym but rather the range or dimension.

Comment: How about "disposition"

Comment: "_Close Request_", "_Submit Decision_", or "_Render Verdict_".  I thought of these because in the workflow of a Process (such as a Judge rendering their final Ruling on a Request) they may either Approve or Deny, or as they say, "_Case Closed_".  If you want to allow the Requester to Submit their Request again, then give them an "_Appeal_" button.  I thought of "_Resolve Request_", but (like other suggestions here) it sounded more like an action that will Redirect you to the next step of Making a Decision, instead of Submitting that Final Decision.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about *review*, from our very own Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR - "*Approval*"**

If the act of approving or rejecting the request is simply the click of a button, then obviously there could be two buttons labeled "Approve" and "Reject" next to the item, but this is clearly a design consideration and nothing to do with the use of English.

If the design is to take the approver (there is a hint already) to a separate screen where the act of approving or rejecting the item must be carried out in more detail, then I would also go with "Approval" as the button label to represent the act of approving (which may still result in rejection).

You generally say that something is sent for "approval" and not "rejection". However, that does not mean it will definitely be approved. It can still be rejected. Similarly, the person doing the approval can be termed an approver, but is never termed a rejecter.

Therefore I maintain that "Approval" as a noun is a good collective term describing the act of approval, which may result in something either being approved or rejected.

From working with enterprise systems, where this query originates, my experience is that the term "approval", as a matter of common usage, is generally deemed and understood to be such an act which may result in either approval or rejection.

Answer (score 4):

*Handle* is another one that immediately springs to mind. When you approve/reject requests, you handle them. In fact, *handle requests* is a very common collocation.

Comment: Similarly, `Process` Requests

Comment: Words like `handle` and `process` are way too generic. When you have a lot of things to name it gets really annoying at times as you end up with lot of stuff that "handles", "does", "processes", "configures", "sets" and "manages" different things. These words don't give you any hints as to what this stuff actually does.

Answer (score 2):

How about 'decision'? As a decision can be either an approval or a denial but never 'pending'.

Comment: _Decision request_ is not English, and _decide request_ would not work at all in the context given.

Comment: Decision is a good choice.  It is not "Decision Request" but "Approver Decision", and the Decision can be Approved, Rejected, Pending, On-Hold...and have a Decision Date, Decision Made By, etc.  It is still a "Request"...and the request requires a Decision.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to see *Approval Requests* as the button. The request is for approval, so the admin can either accept or deny the approval.

Comment: I will have trouble using the 'Approval' since its meaning is referring to `the act of accepting` - so no one can perform the act of disapproving / rejecting - which is termed by `Disapproval`

Answer (score 0):

*Judgment* could work in general, but probably not in your specific context.

Answer (score -2):

Use *comment on request*. It's applicable in context.

Comment: If your suggestion is "comment on request" it is not one word, as required by the OP. If the answer is "request" it is too vague.